# Angular2 dynamic loaded component

Tags: angular

Hello i created component for tabs as in [this tutorial](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html). But now i would like to update this component that tabs always load after open. I add to tab components which loading data from server and when created TabsComponent, load all components. It is any easy way how to create component after click on tab? Please show me how to update code in tutorial.

Comment: your question is confusing and not clear.Please rephrase your question and explain what you exactly need

Comment: you can read more about dynamic components in the [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

Comment: Refer the angular.io site to load components dynamically https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader